# Exclude Calendars (Solspace) from displaying?

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar

I have a MSM site with [Solspace Calendar](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/calendar/) installed. For ease of use on the clients side, they'd like to manage all calendars from one side of the admin which is pretty easy but I'm running into a problem with trying to exclude certain calendars from showing up on one site.

For site A, I'd like to show all calendars EXCEPT specified ones.

For site B, I'd like to ONLY show the specified calendars. This is easy:

```
calendar_name="classes|events"
```

So, for site A, I should be able to do this:

```
calendar_name="NOT classes|events"
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. It hides all my calendars and seems to break the tag.

Any ideas or suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the latest versions of Calendar and EE? If not, please let us know. Also, which Calendar tag are you using, and are you calling the site= parameter in this tag? (site="default_site") :-)

Comment: Yeah I'm on the latest version. I'm not calling the site parameter because the site I want to do that on is the site where the calendars are located under.

I found a workaround (for now), I am using a combination of categories and Low Reorder to display the list of calendars. I still need to filter them out of my "all events" listing however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately as of this writing (latest Calendar version: 1.8.4), using "not" in `calendar_name="not calendar1|calendar2"` isn't available.

However, the `calendar_id=""` parameter should let you exclude calendars. Eg.

```
calendar_id="not 1|5"
```